# OpenMP support in xcode build and automated builds

Tags: xcode, openmp, azure-pipelines

I need to integrate cpp files that are using the omp header file in my xcode project. I followed this article http://antonmenshov.com/2017/09/09/clang-openmp-setup-in-xcode/ which helped me compile the xcode project without issues. However, the paths being /usr/local/... doesn't work for automated builds. I am using VSTS for automated-build of my xcode project and it can't obviously find the file/directory.

I tried to include the header and dylib as part of the xcode project and reference it instead of the /usr/local path. But I don't know how to update the "user defined setting" described in the article which points to the path /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang. The auto-build is failing because of this path.

Is there a way to make this work for automated builds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path for the user-defined setting CC is depend on **where the llvm installed**.

- If you are using **Hosted macOS Preview agent** for VSTS build, you should install llvm first (`brew install llvm`) and then get the path for where llvm installed (it's mainly in the path `/usr/local/opt/llvm`), and then you should use the path `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang` instead.
- If you are using **[private agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-osx?view=vsts)** for VSTS build, the path for user-defined setting CC should be where llvm installed on the agent machine.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to run the brew install commands as part of shell script file as one of the steps in VSTS build.